# Docker / Kubernetes: tried to wipe everything, but I still have a container running on localhost that I can't see with docker ps

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, kubernetes

So I started working with Docker / Kubernetes, and I'm still feeling out the darkness of the room. I foolishly decided to start with a PDF document called "Docker in Practice" from Manning Publications in 2016. I quickly realized that a lot of the commands were outdated. I managed to get the "todo" app running, and since then I moved to other tutorials to learn. At some point my co-worker had me set up Azure-CLI, and I connected to a staging server. After doing that I had trouble with `kubectl config` as `docker ps` would only return containers from the staging server. I eventually decided to remove everything and try starting from scratch. Well now I have the "todo" app still running on my localhost, and I can't seem to find it. I figured that maybe if I downloaded and built it again it might overwrite the old copy, but I was wrong. I can't even see the freshly built "todo" app container. Following is a dump from the last build:

```
PS C:\> cd .\DockerProjects\
PS C:\DockerProjects> docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/7 : FROM node
latest: Pulling from library/node
3192219afd04: Pull complete
17c160265e75: Pull complete
cc4fe40d0e61: Pull complete
9d647f502a07: Pull complete
c8bd59397b26: Pull complete
f9289dfd19be: Pull complete
64c734f3a148: Pull complete
9727b3f70227: Pull complete
c4b3ee6fedd0: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:a36844c0d1a614c769a6fd9cd33f9abf80310b60793bdf01a7ec03dc80692e6e
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:latest
 ---> 448d0873ea84
Step 2/7 : MAINTAINER ian.miell@gmail.com
 ---> Running in d4e54992a581
Removing intermediate container d4e54992a581
 ---> 08f54c9fe76d
Step 3/7 : RUN git clone -q https://github.com/docker-in-practice/todo.git
 ---> Running in 05ed9bee81dd
Removing intermediate container 05ed9bee81dd
 ---> dca1e7fc5987
Step 4/7 : WORKDIR todo
 ---> Running in 3f6140aaa8d5
Removing intermediate container 3f6140aaa8d5
 ---> 9e8c76cd5db4
Step 5/7 : RUN npm install > /dev/null
 ---> Running in 75f398237768
npm WARN deprecated react-tools@0.11.2: react-tools is deprecated. For more information, visit https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html
npm WARN deprecated buffer-browserify@0.2.5: Package not maintained. Recent browserify uses https://github.com/feross/buffer
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for minifyify@4.4.0: wanted: {"node":"0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"13.8.0","npm":"6.13.6"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: minifyify@4.4.0
npm WARN todomvc-swarm@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN todomvc-swarm@0.0.1 license should be a valid SPDX license expression

Removing intermediate container 75f398237768
 ---> 6e8042d80e6e
Step 6/7 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Running in 63aa7da8fc46
Removing intermediate container 63aa7da8fc46
 ---> 7379f012df04
Step 7/7 : CMD ["npm","start"]
 ---> Running in 668c8bfd1539
Removing intermediate container 668c8bfd1539
 ---> 5bf5cbc3bded
Successfully built 5bf5cbc3bded
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
PS C:\DockerProjects> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
PS C:\DockerProjects> docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? I've deleted my kubectl config file, and restarted my PC a few times. That may be obvious because you need to do that for docker desktop to run after install.

Comment: did you try a `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` ?

Comment: Try `docker image ls` I think you are a building an image, which you then need to run to have a container. User Docker's official documentation to get started: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/

Comment: `I eventually decided to remove everything and try starting from scratch.` what does it even mean? `staging server`? do you expect everyone on internet to know what that means in your organization? be serious...

Comment: JoseAngelSanchez I have not tried that, but the computer has been rebooted. Not sure if it will do anything, but I will try to see what it puts out. BenDubs I believe 'docker ps -a' should also return built images that are not running, but I'll also try that out. morgwai I mean that I removed all applications that I installed. Docker, Kubernetes-cli, everything that I thought would be connected. If you don't know what staging and server mean I don't know why you bothered to comment. As I said, I'm still trying to feel out this environment. Be not an ass.

Comment: @BenDubs docker image ls seems to be giving me a list of images on the remote server I connected to.

Comment: Also you're correct. I didn't realize that the build was removing the intermediate containers. After running the image I can see it with 'docker ps'. However it says it's running on localhost:8000, and I can still view the app in my browser after stopping and removing the container.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have configured `DOCKER_*` environment variables (e.g.`DOCKER_HOST`), which are used by your `docker` client. Unset them and your `docker` client will be connecting to your `localhost` docker daemon.

Comment: Thanks. I've unset all environment variables related to docker though, so DOCKER_HOST is using the default value.